# Why I can create multiple server sockets but only one client?

Tags: sockets

Consider the following code:

```c
{
    int Socket1 = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    sockaddr_in SrcSockAddr;
    SrcSockAddr.sin_family = PF_INET;
    SrcSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.2");
    SrcSockAddr.sin_port = htons(5061);

    if( -1 == bind(Socket1, (sockaddr*) &SrcSockAddr, sizeof (SrcSockAddr)) )
       exit(1);

    sockaddr_in DstSockAddr;
    DstSockAddr.sin_family = PF_INET;
    DstSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.3");
    DstSockAddr.sin_port = htons(5061);

    if( connect(Socket1, (sockaddr*)&DstSockAddr, sizeof(DstSockAddr)) )
        exit(2);


    int Socket2 = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if( -1 == bind(Socket2, (sockaddr*) &SrcSockAddr, sizeof (SrcSockAddr)) )
        exit(3);

    DstSockAddr.sin_port = htons(5062);
    if( connect(Socket2, (sockaddr*)&(DstSockAddr), sizeof(DstSockAddr)) )
        exit(4);

    exit(0);
}
```

Assuming that both addresses are correct the result of execution would be 3. I can't bind two sockets to one address and this perfectly make sense.
In server situation, however, accept() returns not a result code like connect() but another descriptor. So I can have multiple incoming connection to one address but only one outgoing.

There is any reason for this?



**Edit:**
Um, well, I've just found out that bind() isn't necessary. But how to set source port of packets then?

Answer (score 0):

You are binding two sockets process to the same `structaddr.PORT`. Which you  can't do. Change another socketaddr struct with a different port number and you should be fine.
IP+PORT must be unique.

```
if( -1 == bind(Socket1, (sockaddr*) &SrcSockAddr, sizeof (SrcSockAddr)) )

 if( -1 == bind(Socket2,
 (sockaddr*) &SrcSockAddr, sizeof (SrcSockAddr)) ) //SrcSockAddr already in use
```

Comment: No. He isn't creating any server sockets at all. They are all client sockets. listen() isn't called anywhere but connect() is.

Comment: @EJP Mmmn, I see.. the use of bind confused me.

Comment: You can `bind()` a client socket, although there aren't many good reasons to do so.

Comment: Um, em.. There is a way of creating client socket without bind()?

Comment: @MadRunner Certainly there is. You only need to call `socket()` and then `connect().` This is the normal usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind two sockets to the same IP:port. However you can `accept()` as many sockets as there are pending inbound connections, from a listening socket that is bound to an IP:port. All those sockets have that IP:port as their local address, but by virtue of inheriting it from the listening socket, not by virtue of the `bind()` function.